# XNextEvent does not work when program isn't ran from terminal

Tags: c, linux, x11, xorg

I'm trying to create a program which reacts to user key presses to display information over the screen.

I was able to create a window to display the information onto, but I have trouble grabbing the key presses - or more specifically, grabbing the key presses when running the program not directly from my terminal.

If I just run it as `./program`, key presses are registered as expected, but if I run it from an sxhkd mapping, it does not work.

I put together a stripped down version of the program without the information displaying to illustrate the issue:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    Display *display;
    Window   window, rootwindow;
    XEvent   event;
    KeySym   escape;

    display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    rootwindow = DefaultRootWindow(display);

    window = XCreateWindow(display, rootwindow,
                           -99, -99, 1, 1, 
                           0, 0, InputOnly,
                           CopyFromParent,
                           0, NULL); 

    XSetWindowAttributes winattr;
    winattr.override_redirect = 1;
    XChangeWindowAttributes(display, window, CWOverrideRedirect, &winattr);

    XGrabKeyboard(display, rootwindow, False, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync, CurrentTime);

    XMapWindow(display, window);
    XSelectInput(display, rootwindow, KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask );

    while (1)
      {
          XNextEvent(display, &event);

          /* keyboard events */
          if (event.type == KeyPress)
          {
              printf( "KeyPress: %x\n", event.xkey.keycode );
              system("echo test >> ~/output");

              /* exit on ESC key press */
              if ( event.xkey.keycode == 0x09 )
                  break;
          }
          else if (event.type == KeyRelease)
          {
              printf( "KeyRelease: %x\n", event.xkey.keycode );
          }
      }

    XUngrabKeyboard(display, CurrentTime);
    XUnmapWindow(display, window);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}
```

You can build it with `gcc main.c -o program -lX11 -lXfixes -lXtst`.

If you run `./program` in your terminal, you should see KeyPress and KeyRelease info being printed out and be able to stop the program with ESC.

But if you map it to a keyboard shortcut somewhere, so it is not run this way, the program won't react to the key presses and won't exit on ESC (you'll need to kill it manually).

I think the culprit is setting `override_redirect` to the created window, but I need to do that since I don't want the program to open a new managed window but rather an overlay.

I'm not quite sure what the issue is, so the title of this question might need correcting.

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? And if so, what am I doing wrong?

`lsof` output:

```
0r      CHR                1,3       0t0       2051 /dev/null
1w      CHR                1,3       0t0       2051 /dev/null
2w      REG                8,3   3590712     524358 /home/eyfl/.xsession-errors
3u     unix 0x00000000648e641e       0t0    4028921 type=STREAM
4u     unix 0x00000000f842df04       0t0      24192 /tmp/bspwm_0_0-socket type=STREAM
```

Comment: You're writing to standard output.  What is standard output connected to when you run the program from a keyboard shortcut?  (If you don't know, you can find out with `lsof`.)

Comment: To clarify, my goal is not writing to standard output, but running arbitrary code in reaction to key being pressed. The indication that the program is doing what I want is if it terminated upon pressing ESC when ran from a keyboard shortcut (which it doesn't).  I edited the main question to add the parts of `lsof` without linked libs.

Comment: Yes, I understand that writing to standard output is not the end goal. But because the test program _is_ writing to standard output, which goes somewhere different when the program is run under a terminal than when it's run directly by the session manager, that could have explained why it doesn't work in the latter case. (But writing to /dev/null should not cause the program to hang, so I suppose this is a red herring.)

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification - that's good thinking. 
So I take it that there isn't anything in the example I posted that immediately strikes you as a problem? I might be using the wrong tools for the job, but this is the only approach I managed to find that does what I need (well, when running from terminal it does).

Comment: I'm not an X11 expert, unfortunately.  I think you're probably right to suspect the override-redirect thing, but I don't have an alternative to suggest.